# Sending a string to python script using PHP and get the output back to the PHP script

Tags: sentiment-analysis

What i am trying to do is call a python script using PHP which is performing a sentiment analysis and return back the result of the analysis in the form of polarity either -ve or +ve.
The reason why im calling Python from PHP is that i have an android application which uses PHP and i dont know if we can call Pyhton from android studio.
Here is my Python Script:

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe
import sys
from textblob import TextBlob
import os
arg=sys.argv[1]

analysis = Textblob(arg)
polar = analysis.sentiment.polarity
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print(polar)
```

And here is my PHP script

```
<?php

$my="This is very Good";

echo exec('C:/Python27/python test.py "'.$my.'"');

?>
```

I dont know where im going wrong but when i only execute my script on the xampp server the following error occurs

"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: test.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that something is being printed before the http header "Content-Type: text/html\n" is being printed.

Perhaps the py script is printing a warning or an error, or your php script has character(s) before the `<?php` .

To troubleshoot, try running the php and py scripts from a terminal. It will show exactly what is being printed out before the header:

```
# /PATH_TO_PHP/php the_test_script.php
# /Python27/python.exe test.py
```